# geom_text mapping adds extra y axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

```
Bacp <- ggplot(BAC22, aes(y = value, fill = group$treatment)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_grid(group$zone~., scales = "free_x", switch = "both")+
  geom_text(BAC22,mapping = aes(x = 0.3, y = 0.005, label = label,
                                       hjust   = -0.1,
                                       vjust   = -1))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  theme(
    axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
    strip.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"), 
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=10), 
    legend.position="none",
    plot.title = element_textbox_simple(hjust = 0.5, size = 14, fill = "white", halign=0.5),
    plot.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 0.5))+
  coord_flip()+ 
  ylab("")
```

I am making this boxplot where I need to have a label.
How can I get rid of the "x" added on the y axis, when I use the geom_text(mapping)?

[image]

I tried to add `show.legend=FALSE`  or `geom_text(aes geom_text(aes(label = label)`  but then I get an error asking me to define the mapping

data

```
> dput(BAC22)
structure(list(Sample = c("R8-A-rep1", "R8-A-rep2", "R8-A-rep3", 
"R8-A-rep4", "R8-B-rep1", "R8-B-rep2", "R8-B-rep3", "R8-B-rep4", 
"R8-C-rep1", "R8-C-rep2", "R8-C-rep3", "R8-C-rep4", "R7-A-rep1", 
"R7-A-rep2", "R7-A-rep3", "R7-A-rep4", "R7-B-rep1", "R7-B-rep2", 
"R7-B-rep3", "R7-B-rep4", "R7-C-rep1", "R7-C-rep2", "R7-C-rep3", 
"R7-C-rep4", "R6-A-rep1", "R6-A-rep2", "R6-A-rep3", "R6-A-rep4", 
"R6-B-rep1", "R6-B-rep2", "R6-B-rep3", "R6-B-rep4", "R6-C-rep1", 
"R6-C-rep2", "R6-C-rep3", "R6-C-rep4", "R5-A-rep1", "R5-A-rep2", 
"R5-A-rep3", "R5-A-rep4", "R5-B-rep1", "R5-B-rep2", "R5-B-rep3", 
"R5-B-rep4", "R5-C-rep1", "R5-C-rep2", "R5-C-rep3", "R5-C-rep4"
), value = c(0.0143262603054467, 0.010717230008244, 0.00640916082720902, 
0.00970191843364502, 0.00951386471748463, 0.01283478872414, 0.0109367813154801, 
0.00827823189462175, 0.00975483870967742, 0.016588785046729, 
0.00981712349593849, 0.00633613179154126, 0.00837009854450996, 
0.01093083672369, 0.00971632244519311, 0.00860979832483272, 0.00815192640495491, 
0.00755380303102285, 0.00713447547524055, 0.016195351178988, 
0.00678484399636867, 0.00672771444589796, 0.00545966889749912, 
0.00788903013534734, 0.0127865061552064, 0.0106606942889138, 
0.0111904880851276, 0.0148022324678476, 0.0138476303642429, 0.0110281447443998, 
0.0111323512875295, 0.00980920556214293, 0.0146841115512343, 
0.0148008115086684, 0.0134508585112345, 0.01535, 0.0107545839210155, 
0.0113739305485657, 0.00890535980972399, 0.00639635129873742, 
0.013368315842079, 0.0139162310773199, 0.0135098743267504, 0.0130310603355944, 
0.0118022010856033, 0.00890464608154347, 0.014367306396112, 0.0100169404139353
), label = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"P < 0.001", NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What is your `group` dataframe?

Comment: You can probably set `axis.title.y = element_blank()` in the theme (not tested).

Comment: @teunbrand is correct, see response

Answer (score 0):

@[teunbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11374827/teunbrand) is correct, here's the solution.

First, create reproducible data

```
# Load required packages 
library(tidyverse)

# Set randomisation seed 
set.seed(123)

    # Create reproducible data
    df_test <- 
      tibble(
        group_a = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = 500, replace = T),
        group_b = sample(c("Amber", "Burgundy", "Cerulean", "Daffodil"), size = 500, replace = T),
        value = rnorm(500, 0, 1),
        label = ifelse(value > sd(value)*1.96, "Sig", NA)
      )
```

Second, create the graph with the offending label

```
# Create a graph with the annoying label to be removed 
df_test %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = value,
      y = value,
      label = label,
      fill = group_b)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_text() +
  facet_grid(
    group_a ~ .,
    scales = "free_x", 
    switch = "both") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10), 
    axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    strip.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"), 
    strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
    legend.position ="none",
    plot.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  ylab("")
```

[image]

Third, add `axis.title.y = element_blank()` as @[teunbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11374827/teunbrand) says

```
# Create a graph with the annoying label to be removed 
df_test %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = value,
      y = value,
      label = label,
      fill = group_b)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_text() +
  facet_grid(
    group_a ~ .,
    scales = "free_x", 
    switch = "both") +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_blank(), # <======= Add this to the code
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10), 
    axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
    strip.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"), 
    strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
    legend.position ="none",
    plot.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  ylab("")
```

[image]